# could not set break point in safari 10 for google polymer 1.x

Tags: debugging, safari, polymer

I'm trying to debug my polymer 1.x app on safari 10 but the breakpoint that I set does not catch anything. I've tried to use console.out to verify that it did go through that break point but safari's break point did not catch that. With my other project i.e. angular 1 project, break point works as expected.

Comment: i'm able to do it with polymer's shop demo

Comment: I'm faced with the same issue: did you find a solution in the meantime?